# How do I deploy an applications to Kubernetes with Minikube?

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I would like to do something like this, but all Kubernetes quickstart demos are just for deploying a simple applications and not multiple.

How would I create a yaml file that can deploy multiple applications like this with Minikube?

- Deploy tomcat to minikube
- Deploy sample.war to tomcat (https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/appdev/sample/ )
- Bind tomcat service to hostport 8090
- Deploy nginx/apache to minikube
- Bind nginx/apache to hostport 8080

Answer (score 1):

If you're happy to use Spring boot embedded tomcat you could look at https://dzone.com/articles/minions-in-minikube-a-kubernetes-intro-for-java-de or https://dzone.com/articles/configuring-java-apps-with-kubernetes-configmaps-a These are pieces I've written so happy to receive feedback and help as I can. Using Spring boot and the kubernetes Ingress concept (which can be nginx) is more common than non-embedded tomcat and nginx as a server. (But with minikube you have to enable an add-on for Ingress.)